# Error (use-package): Failed to install magit: Package `magit-' is unavailable

Tags: init-file, magit, use-package, docker, emacs-nox

I am starting to build up a `.emacs` file to be used as a development environment within Docker containers. I get this error when starting emacs-nox in a Docker container.

```
Error (use-package): Failed to install magit: Package `magit-' is unavailable
Error (use-package): Cannot load magit
```

Here is the contents of my `.emacs`:

```lisp
;; require package
(require 'package)
    
;; add melpa stable
(add-to-list 'package-archives
        '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
    
;; add melpa
(add-to-list 'package-archives
        '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
    
;; Initialise packages
(package-initialize)
    
;; get latest package information
(package-refresh-contents)
    
;; add use package
;; so packages can automatically be installed
;; required for reuse across computer or docker containers
(package-install 'use-package)
    
;; add magit for git
(use-package magit
  :ensure t
    :pin melpa-stable)
```

Comment: Which emacs version are you using?

Comment: M-x version:  "GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) of 2017-09-12 on hullmann, modified by Debian"

Comment: I've run into this issue before. Run `M-x package-refresh-contents` and try again?

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan that did not work for me.  I did `M-x package-refresh-contents` and then `M-x eval-region` on `(use-package magit :ensure t :pin melpa-stable)`.  I get the same error message.

Comment: Tried install the `magit` using `M-x package-install RET magit` ?

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan  thanks for the suggestions. `M-x eval-region` on `(package-install 'magit)` gives this error
 `Package 'magit-' is unavailable`.  `M-x package-install RET magit` gives a list of possible completions that does not include `magit` but has many magit-* suggestions.  Doing `M-x package-list-packages` also does not list `magit` but does list many magit-* packages.

Comment: @learningemacs they both use the same packages list. Add melpa to your package list using this: `(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))` and restart emacs and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @ChakravarthyRaghunandan and @Kaligule and rereading the Melpa getting started I have been able to use use-package to install magit in a docker container in emacs-nox.  The dockerfile starts with `FROM debian:stable`.

At [Melpa - Getting Started](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started), it says:

> There are some problems using the https location with Emacs on
> Windows. There is currently no know easy fix for this. You can still
> use MELPA by using the non-SSL location by replacing https with http.

So I tried using `http` instead of `https` in the Melpa URLs.

```lisp
(add-to-list 'package-archives
        '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
    
(add-to-list 'package-archives
        '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
```

That got it working.

Comment: I think an answer that uses `https` would be a better answer.

Comment: I am on Debian with emacs 27.1 and using http instead of https fixed my error of the same type when trying to install the package zetteldeft.

Comment: just ran into this on a mac with same version of emacs and http:// worked for me also. Sigh.

Comment: trouble with http is that it doesn't solve issues with other lower level packages that have explicit https melpa get breaking with a 443 problem.